# Pass parameters to checkout/onepage

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to pass a parameter in the URL line like this:

http://domain.com/website/checkout/onepage/quotation/1

When i try this i have a error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Is a problem with url, i modified the url:

http://domain.com/website/checkout/onepage/index/quotation/1